# Facebook share button shows irrelevant title,description and image

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-like, meta-tags

I know there are a lot of questions like these but I am not able to an answer. So decided to ask a new one. I have a website which shows Events and I want to share the event on facebook so it should create a share box with the current events Title, Description and Image.

I have included my facebook SDK in the body section:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '843460125752678',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.5'
        });
};
(function (d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and I have included the facebook like button somewhere as :

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mywebsite.com" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

I want to add meta tags from code-behind as below in Page_Load

```
        HtmlMeta hm7 = new HtmlMeta();
        hm7.Attributes.Add("property", "fb:app_id");
        hm7.Content = "my id here";
        this.Header.Controls.Add(hm7);

        HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();
        tag.Attributes.Add("property", "og:title");
        tag.Content = lblTitle.Text;
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);

        HtmlMeta tag1 = new HtmlMeta();
        tag1.Attributes.Add("property", "og:description");
        tag1.Content = "Click for more info";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag1);

        HtmlMeta tagurl = new HtmlMeta();
        tagurl.Attributes.Add("property", "og:url");
        tagurl.Content = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(tagurl);

        HtmlMeta tagimg = new HtmlMeta();
        tagimg.Attributes.Add("property", "og:image");
        tagimg.Content = "some image url";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(tagimg);
```

But when I click on the share button, title comes up as "Enter your title here",description as "Your description comes here" and it takes my website logo as the image all the time.

What could be the problem? Looks like I am setting the meta tags twice..first in html and then in code-behind. But even when I remove the tags from html, it stills gives the same output.

Update: I tried debugging the code in facebook and I get the below warning messages

1.The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
2.The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
3.The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
4.The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

and error message as below:

fb:app_id hasn't been included in the meta tags. Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog. Otherwise, the default app id( 966242223397117 ) will be assigned.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: This would be easier to check if you told us the actual URL.

Comment: http://sportstruggle.com/EventView.aspx?EventId=5

Comment: When I debug that and see what it will look like in the Share dialog, it shows title “Nutrition Workshop” and “Click for more info” as description. The specified image is not shown, because it is too small (as the debug tool clearly states.)

Comment: Yes, looks like it is working now.Facebook needs 'fetch new information' everytime.

Comment: Yes, when you change your OG meta tags, you need to refresh Facebook’s cache. (If you need this for a larger number of URLs, you can also [trigger a re-scrape via API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, delete meta tag for OpenGraph (og:title, og:description, so on) from your design code. Then try to change `Page.Header.Controls` to `this.Header.Controls`.

Make sure that you inserted javascript code as soon as body section begins. If still does not working, try to use the next code to make a link to share:

```
Share via:&nbsp;<a class="text-capitalize" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=your_site.com">Facebook</a>
```

Hope it helps. If still will not work, make a comment to this answer, we will check again.

Comment: And it would be good, if you will add next meta tag:
HtmlMeta hm7 = new HtmlMeta();
hm7.Attributes.Add("property", "fb:app_id");
hm7.Content = "11111111111111111"; //your fb_application_id

Comment: I've made the necessary changes and in the View Source code I have the below meta tags created :  <meta property="og:title" content="Nutrition Workshop by Cafe Nutrition" /><meta property="og:description" content="Click for more info" /><meta property="og:url" content="mywebsite.com/EventView.aspx?EventId=5"; /><meta property="og:image" content="mywebsite.com/ProfilePictures/nbfn.png; /> which are all as expected

Comment: but I still get the same problem "title comes up as "Enter your title here",description as "Your description comes here" and it takes my website logo as the image all the time."

Comment: I don't know exactly, but what if you add "http://" to your url? I think it causes an error, caz' it can't find that. And try to debug your page via Facebook debugger: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug